# Notice: Use of undefined constant self - assumed 'self' , When put in property_exists as the first argument

Tags: php, oop, properties, constants, self

I'm trying to use `self` instead of typing the class name inside `propery_exists` function as follows :

```
private static function instantiate($record){
    $user = new self;
    foreach($record as $name => $value){
        if(isset($user->$name) || property_exists(self, $name)){
            $user->$name = $value;
        }
    }
    return $user;
}
```

But when i ran this script it get an error :

> Notice: Use of undefined constant self - assumed 'self' in
>   /var/www/photo_gallery/includes/User.php on line 36

Line 36 is the line where `property_exists` method is called.

When i change self to `User` (the class name). It works perfectly.

I want to know why using `self` is giving such a notice ? Doesn't `self` refer to the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `self` to refer to the current class. **Not class name**.

Try using magic constants:

```
if(isset($user->$name) || property_exists(__CLASS__, $name)){
```

From php manual: `__CLASS__`

The class name. (Added in PHP 4.3.0) As of PHP 5 this constant returns the class name as it was declared (case-sensitive). In PHP 4 its value is always lowercased. The class name includes the namespace it was declared in (e.g. Foo\Bar). Note that as of PHP 5.4 **CLASS** works also in traits. When used in a trait method, **CLASS** is the name of the class the trait is used in.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

**An example:**

```
class Test {
    public function __construct(){
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
```

**Output:**

```
Test
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks Vahid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self::class` this way you avoid magic constants.

As an addition you can use something like this to make an instance from an array:

```
public function __construct(array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (property_exists(self::class, $key)) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this approach, using self::class instead of the magic constant for the current class.